# Unable to load suitable drive from java 18 on linux 24.02.1 wsl with mysql version 8.0.31

Tags: java, mysql-connector

I get the following error when trying to execute a Java program with SQL code:

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for
> jdbc:mysql://localhost/opiejbc1

I have installed the driver mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar in /usr/share/java

I have called the class with java -cp ./:/usr/share/java TestApplication
and with CLASSPATH=./:/usr/share/java set.

My Java code is as follows:

```java
import java.sql.*;

public class TestApplication {
   static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/opiejbc1";
   static final String USER = "opiejbc1";
   static final String QUERY = "SELECT * FROM Test1";

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // Open a connection
      try(Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, "");
         Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
         ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(QUERY);) {
         // Extract data from result set
         while (rs.next()) {
            // Retrieve by column name
            System.out.print("Name: " + rs.getInt("Name"));
            System.out.print(", Phone: " + rs.getInt("Phone"));
         }
      } catch (SQLException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } 
   }
}
```

I have tried inserting `Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");` immediately after the try statement, but then I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
        Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)

        at TestApplication.main(TestApplication.java:10)
```

What am I doing wrong?

I have tried all the recommended solutions as far as I know, but I still get those errors.

Comment: You need to include the full name of the jar fire and its path if it's part of a classpath

Comment: In general you should not use the `CLASSPATH` environment variable, but specify it explicitly with `-cp`, or through the manifest of your Java app, but if you do, make sure it references the JAR files, not the directory containing the JAR files.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by @g00se, the real problem is that the JAR file for the Connector/J driver is not on your **runtime** classpath.  So the `java` runtime cannot find it.

Solution: put the JAR file on the classpath.

Notes:

1. If you use a `-cp` option, the `CLASSPATH` environment variable is ignored.
2. If you put a directory on the classpath, you are NOT telling the `java`  to put JAR files (in that directory) on the classpath.
3. If you wanted to put all JAR files in (say) "/usr/share/java" on the classpath, you could use a wildcard entry; e.g. `-cp .:/usr/share/java/*.jar`.  Note that the `*.jar` is not shell globbing.  It needs to be processed by the `java` command.  (In some cases you may need to escape it to prevent globbing.)
4. You should (IMO) take the time to read the Oracle documentation on [how the classpath works](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html).

---

Adding a `Class.forName` call is NOT recommended (except by people who don't understand the problem).  If the drivers are on the classpath then `DriverManager` will find them.  And if they are not on the classpath, then using `Class.forName` is going to fail.

But the reason that you got a compilation error was that you were inserting it at the wrong place:

```
 try ( // HERE is the wrong place
      Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, "");
      Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(QUERY);) {
```

The *try with resources* syntax only allows variable declarations with initializers in that  context.  A `Class.forName` call is not such a thing.

I haven't checked, but I think that inserting

```
Class dummy = Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
```

at `// HERE` in the above would make the compiler happier.  But DON'T.  It is unnecessary.  It won't help.  See above for the correct solution.

Comment: *Note that the *.jar is not shell globbing* It is the path concatenation that will stop globbing. But if you put your main class in /usr/share/share and removed the current directory from the path, it would be expanded unless globbing has been turned off. That might create a large and redundant path if done with /usr/share/java. Single-quoting it will stop that. I have found that to not always work.

Comment: @g00se - Yes, it usually will.  But if the classpath has only one component, it won't. Hence, I said "In some cases ....".